# Custom Form Validation and Submit

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, validation

I have a form validation run when the submit button is selected but i do not want the default submit function to run.  Instead i want to run an ajax post code to store the data in the form along with post the data from server side.

I am having trouble finding where to cancel the default submit and add in the ajax code.

Here is the validate code i have

```
    $("#formEnroll").validate({
    errorElement:"p",
    submitHandler: function(form) {
            var phoneNumber = form.day_phone.value;             
            var phoneParts  = phoneNumber.split("-");
            form.dayArea.value = phoneParts[0];
            form.dayPrefix.value = phoneParts[1];
            form.daySuffix.value = phoneParts[2];               
            form.submit();
    }

});
```

And here is the ajax code i want to run instead of the default submission

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/php/localProxy.php",
    data: $('#formEnroll').serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
            document.location = 'http://www.xxxx.com/thank-you';

    },
    error: function () {
            alert('There was a problem!');  // handle error
    }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call the the ajax function instead of form.submit();
form.submit(); will submit your code using default submission.

```
  $('#formEnroll').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 

        $(this).validate({
            errorElement:"p",
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                var phoneNumber = form.day_phone.value;             
                var phoneParts  = phoneNumber.split("-");
                form.dayArea.value = phoneParts[0];
                form.dayPrefix.value = phoneParts[1];
                form.daySuffix.value = phoneParts[2];               
                submitform();
            }
        });
    })

    function submitform(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/localProxy.php",
        data: $('#formEnroll').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
                document.location = 'http://www.xxxx.com/thank-you';

        },
        error: function () {
                alert('There was a problem!');  // handle error
        }
    });

    }
```

Comment: this stops the default from working, but nothing is submitting after validation.  do i need to call the function anywhere else besides the submithandler?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your validate plugin into a generic form submit function to stop standard execution.

```
$('#formEnroll').on('submit', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission

    // Run validation
    $(this).validate({
        errorElement:"p",
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var phoneNumber = form.day_phone.value;             
            var phoneParts  = phoneNumber.split("-");
            form.dayArea.value = phoneParts[0];
            form.dayPrefix.value = phoneParts[1];
            form.daySuffix.value = phoneParts[2];               
            submitform(); // call your ajax function here
        }
    });
});

function submitform(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/localProxy.php",
        data: $('#formEnroll').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
                document.location = 'http://www.xxxx.com/thank-you';

    },
    error: function () {
        alert('There was a problem!');  // handle error
    }
});
```

Instead of using the event object `e` you can also just `return false;` at the end of the `.on` function to stop default events from firing.

Comment: and how would i incorporate the ajax code to run?  i tried this code you have and tried to incorporate ajax code but it would always go back to default submission

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data by ajax using the click event in the jquery by clicking the submit button and that function should `return false` for avoiding the default submission by the way you can send the data using ajax and avoid the default submission.